# Putty Login error through SSH (Network error: Connenction timeout)

Tags: ssh, putty

I am trying to login into one(X) server using putty (port 22), it is showing Fatal Error. In Pop-up (Network error: Connection timed out).

But when I am in different server(Y) on command prompt using

```
ssh (X)hostname
```

it is working, only issue with the putty.

At the same time, I am able to logged into some different servers(Y,Z) through putty.

Comment: Crossposted here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222784/putty-login-error-through-ssh-network-error-connenction-timeout

Comment: Are machines X, Y and Z on the same network or otherwise mutually reachable?

Answer (score 0):

Go `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and find the line `# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120`. Now change 120 to 300 and save it. I think it will give you 5 minutes more than 2 minutes for logIN.

Comment: Finally we found the problem it is firewall issue. Now we fixed it.Thanks for your response guys.

Answer (score 0):

I started getting time-outs for SSH connection after I installed `firewalld` package on Ubuntu 15.04.
It must be something in the firewall settings that instructs the SSH server to refuse connection to specific clients (evidently, Putty is among such clients).

Removing `firewalld` resolved the problem for me.

```
apt-get autoremove firewalld
```

If you still need a firewall, you will need to find out which one you're using and adjust the settings accordingly.

Comment: No need to remove Firewall! Firewall is very important. Instead use the following command: sudo ufw allow 22